# Can there be whitespace between Java annotations

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations

I was debugging some odd code and I found a problem.

When my code looked like this.  That is, with a space between the annotation EclipseLink was not able to pick-up some of the annotations.

```
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "EDGE_PK", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)

  @SequenceGenerator(name = "EDGE_PK", sequenceName = "SEQ_EDGE_ID")
  @Column(name = "EDGE_ID", nullable = false)
  private Long edgeId;
```

If I remove the space then the system started working as expected.

Is it legal to have a space between annotations like I have or does it change the meaning?  Ie, some apply to the class instead of the variable.

Edit: I'm using Eclipse right now

Comment: You are not being very specific about what's not working. If the issue is at runtime when EclipseLink is processing your classes, then this doesn't have anything to do with Eclipse IDE. I recommend filing a bug report at "https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=EclipseLink". Otherwise, you will need to be more specific as to what function isn't behaving as expected.

Comment: I didn't the the specific problem mattered in this case.  If Java handles annotations differently depending on whitespace then bringing up sequence generation won't be productive.  However, if Java doesn't confirm whitespace then I'll have to get in touch with the EclipseLink people.

Comment: Java specifies that the whitespace between annotations is not significant. What is causing the problem is a different matter. Java itself doesn't handle processing of annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whitespace between annotations is completely irrelevant, it seems to me that you found a quirk in your IDE regarding annotation on-screen display.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that this is an IDE issue.  IntelliJ IDEA does not have an issue with these types of annotations, and I would suspect that `javac` would not, either (they don't care about whitespace anyway).